# .off progress update on 'timeupdate' and resume later with .on

Tags: javascript, event-handling, video.js

Using the video.js media player, I want to continue playing media, but temporarily pause updating the progress indicators (progress-bar and current time indicator). After a while I want to resume the progress indicators.

These progress indicators listen to the 'timeupdate' event. I can not figure out how to .off specific functions. With `video.off('timeupdate');` I remove all handlers for the 'timeupdate' event. But I don't want to remove all 'timeupdate' handlers, just 2 specific ones:

```
.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.updateContent()
.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.update()
```

I lost track of all different ways I've tried to remove specific handlers.

The following didn't work:

```
video.player_.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.off(video.player_, 'timeupdate', this.updateContent)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'guid' of undefined
```

This does not raise an error but also doesn't do anything:

```
video.player_.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.off(video.player_, 'timeupdate', video.player_.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.updateContent)
```

With this function I can later restore the progress display:

```
video.on('timeupdate', function(){
                this.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.updateContent();
                this.controlBar.remainingTimeDisplay.updateContent();
                this.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.updateARIAAttributes();
                this.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.update();
});
```

But I don't think this is right either.

I make a jsfiddle to show what I'm trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/bj23381d/2/ The progress updating is paused, but all other events that listen to 'timeupdate' have been removed too.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding functions to the objects for removing and adding their event listeners.

```
var video = videojs('example_video_1');

function startStopUpdate() {

    vjs.CurrentTimeDisplay.prototype.stopUpdateContent = function(){
        this.off(this.player_, 'timeupdate', this.updateContent);
    }

    vjs.CurrentTimeDisplay.prototype.startUpdateContent = function(){
        this.on(this.player_, 'timeupdate', this.updateContent);
    }

    vjs.SeekBar.prototype.stopUpdate = function(){
        this.off(this.player_, 'timeupdate', this.update);
    }

    vjs.SeekBar.prototype.startUpdate = function(){
        this.on(this.player_, 'timeupdate', this.update);
    }   
}

videojs.plugin('startStopUpdate', startStopUpdate);
video.startStopUpdate();

function stopUpdate(){
    console.log('stopUpdate');   
    video.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.stopUpdateContent();
    video.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.stopUpdate();
}

function startUpdate(){
    console.log('startUpdate');
    video.controlBar.currentTimeDisplay.startUpdateContent();
    video.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.startUpdate();
};

setTimeout(stopUpdate, 2000);
setTimeout(startUpdate, 10000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bj23381d/4/